# Run Regex in R dataframe based on structure of string

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds

Having below mentioned dataframe where regex working fine for first 2 string but not working for third string (Where the format of string is differ from above two). I want a code which check first format of string and than run regex to get best result out of the string to give below mentioned six fields in Output data.

```
    library(stringr)
    input = structure(list(
      `Sr. No.`=c("1", "2","3"), 
      String=c(
        "ABCD, your Account XX1987 has been credited with EUR 22,500.00 on 30-Oct-17. Info: CAM*CASH DEPOSIT*ELISH SEC. The Available Balance is EUR 22,951.57.", 
        "WXYZ, Your Ac XXXXXXXX1987 is debited with USD 5,000.00 on 14 May. Info. MMT*125485645*99999999. Your Net Available Balance is USD 20,531.38.,
"INR 187,314.00 credited to your A/c No XXXXXXX1234 on 31/10/17 through NEFT with UTR )")), 
      .Names=c("Sr. No.", "String"), row.names=1:2, class="data.frame")

    rule_13 = str_match(input$String, "(credit|debit)ed[^0-9]*((?:EUR|USD|INR|Rs) [0-9,.]+)")
    rule_2 = str_match(input$String, "(?:Account|your Ac|your a/c|your acc|XX)[^0-9]*([0-9]+)")
    rule_4 = str_match(input$String, " on ([0-9]+[ -](?:(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)|[0-9]+)(?:[ -][0-9]+)?)")
    rule_5 = str_match(input$String, "\\bInfo\\b[^\\w\\d]+(.+)(?=\\. )")
    rule_6 = str_match(input$String, "(?:Available Balance|Net Balance|Balance)[^0-9]*([0-9,.]+[0-9])")

    data.frame(
        Sr.No=input$`Sr. No.`,
        Type=rule_13[,2],
        Acc=rule_2[,2],
        Fig=rule_13[,3],
        Data=rule_4[,2],
        Desc=rule_5[,2],
        Balance=rule_6[,2])
```

Output:

```
Sr.No   Type  Acc       Fig      Data                       Desc   Balance
    1 credit 1987 22,500.00 30-Oct-17 CAM*CASH DEPOSIT*ELISH SEC 22,951.57
    2  debit 1987  5,000.00    14 May     MMT*125485645*99999999 20,531.38
    3 credit 1234           31/10/2017
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you just kept the part of code that gives you trouble. It is not quite clear what is not working here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew as you can see in the output now i am not getting Fig which is "187,314.00" in third case because my string format is different.

Comment: Try [`(?:^|(credit|debit)ed[^0-9]*)((?:EUR|USD|INR|Rs) [0-9,.]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/XNeLDZ/1). Or [`(?:(credit|debit)ed[^0-9]*)?((?:EUR|USD|INR|Rs) [0-9,.]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/XNeLDZ/2)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew its giving NA in first two rows: `1 NA 1987 NA 30-Oct-17 CAM*CASH DEPOSIT*ELISH SEC NA
    2  NA 1987  NA    14 May     MMT*125485645*99999999 NA`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you help here my all regex are working fine except for "INR 187,314.00 credited to your A/c No XXXXXXX1234 on 31/10/17 through NEFT with UTR " this type of string. i just want a regex to take care this time of string whenever come in data frame else run old regex.

Comment: Check [this approach](https://ideone.com/7a646u). Add a `rule_13_1` line, and then using `ifelse` check if `rule_13` got a valid match, else use the result in `rule_13_1[,2]`

Comment: So, have you had time to check the approach?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes and that worked but now i'm only stuck with `Fig=rule_13[,3],` here that how to add `Fig=rule_13_1[,2],` in data frame with ifelse.

Comment: See my answer with all necessary details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use two regexps to make things simpler and more readable: after running your `rule_13` regex and then an additional regex to match the other format, then check if the Group 1 or 2 of Regex 1 matched, and if not, use the value you obtained with the second regex.

```
input <- "INR 187,314.00 credited to your A/c No XXXXXXX1234 on 31/10/17 through NEFT with UTR )"
rule_13 = str_match(input, "(credit|debit)ed[^0-9]*((?:EUR|USD|INR|Rs) [0-9,.]+)")
##> rule_13
##     [,1] [,2] [,3]
##[1,] NA   NA   NA  
rule_13_1 = str_match(input, "(?:EUR|USD|INR|Rs)\\s*(\\d[0-9,.]*)\\b")
##> rule_13_1
##     [,1]             [,2]        
##[1,] "INR 187,314.00" "187,314.00"
fig1 <- ifelse(!is.na(rule_13[,2]),rule_13[,2],rule_13_1[,2])
fig1
## => [1] "187,314.00"
```

So, you will just have to replace `Fig=rule_13[,3],` with `Fig=fig1,`.

The second pattern matches

- `(?:EUR|USD|INR|Rs)` - either `EUR`, `USD`, `INR` or `Rs` substring
- `\\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\\d[0-9,.]*)` - Group 1 (will be in `[,2]`, the `[,1]` is the whole match): a digit followed with 0+ digits, `,` or `.`
- `\\b` - a word boundary.